# Working in SQL, trying to create a query using date ranges, but some values are 0000-00-00 and need to replace them

Tags: mysql, sql, date, case

I'm trying to create a query in which the `UserRecordID`'s displayed are the ones in which 
(1) the `EventCreatedDate` is greater than `UpgradeCreatedDate` 
and 
(2) the `EventCreatedDate` is less than the `UpgradeExpirationDate`

So something like:

```
WHERE Event.CreatedDate > UpgradeCreatedDate
    AND Event.CreatedDate < UpgradeExpirationDate
```

However, the problem is that some UserRecordID's do not have an expiration date and are represented by `"0000-00-00"` and SQL seems to see this as a really small date, when I want the query to see it as a really large date (essentially infinity, since the upgrade never expires). So whenever the `UpgradeExpirationDate` is `0000-00-00` my current query always sees the Event.CreatedDate as greater than the `UpgradeExpirationDate` when I want it to be less than. Is there a way to account for this? I tried using a `CASE` statement, but still couldn't get it to work the way I wanted.

Comment: Does the `UpgradeExpirationDate` permit NULLs? It would make more sense to have null values there instead of zero-valued dates, if it were practical to fix the application code that is inserting those values.

Answer (score 1):

one thing.  you can restate all the 0000-00-00 to 9999-12-31 in the database.. then everything you do will work just fine.  I have typically used 9999-12-31 to represent "forever" vs 0000-00-00.  Then your SQL will work as expected in all cases.

if you dont do that .. you will have to tac onto the where clause

```
WHERE 

    Event.CreatedDate > UpgradeCreatedDate 
AND (Event.CreatedDate < UpgradeExpirationDate OR 
     UpgradeExpirationDate = '0000-00-00')
```

Comment: Currently I'm not able to modify the database, but this approach to adding "OR" to the WHERE clause works really well. Thanks brother!